# swift .framework update causes 'use of undeclared type errors'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

If I create a fresh xcode 7 project and then add my whatever.framework to the project and import the framework and then declare an instance of one of it's classes it works fine.

If I delete the framework and try to re-install I encounter **"use of undeclared type error"** on any of the classes I try to instantiate.

I've tried all the basic clean, delete derived data and restarts I can think of.

Answer (score 6):

My issue was entirely unrelated to updating the framework. That was a red herring. Somewhere in that process I managed to mismatch my build device. If I build my framework with 'Generic ios Device' selected but use it in an app where I am building to the simulator I see this error. If I set my app to also build to a 'Generic ios Device' the errors go away and it compiles fine.

Comment: This is a very important note. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Build phases > Link Binary with libraries > Select the framework you want to delete and hit the (-) button? If you have done this and the error still remains, I think you have to clear the framework files from your project so that you can add a new version of the framework.

Comment: I am not removing the framework for good, but rather attempting to update it. So I delete it, clean up and delete derived data and then drop in a new .framework  and relink everything. In an attempt to resolve my issue my framework update is the same as the original with only an updated version number.

Comment: Yes, deleted from build phases. After selecting .framework file in xcode and hitting delete button and selecting 'trash' option. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Before adding the new one have you made sure that the old ones are removed from your project in Xcode and from your project folder?

Comment: Strange, then my recommendation is if your framework is supporting https://cocoapods.org/ use it instead, if you need an explanation of Coca Pods read here https://cocoapods.org/about and if you want an installation guide https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html Good luck.